# Python equivalent to PHP include

Tags: php, python, include

I need a Python equivalent of PHP's include function. I know of execfile(), but that doesn't work the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`import`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), with a try/except on `ImportError`:

```
try:
    import modulename
except ImportError:
    print 'importing modulename failed'
```

Without catching `ImportError` it is the equivalent of `require`, sorta-kinda.

Do note that python will only execute the module code *once* (making this more a `include_once` or `require_once` statement. Functions in the module can be called more than once, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to set a string variable in your script to the contents of an external file *a la*  php ([Example #6 Using output buffering to include a PHP file into a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) ...) then this might work:

```
s = open('file.abc').read()
```

You may also use [context-managers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/)

```py
with open('file.abc', "r") as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Comment: Make sure you close the file by calling `.close()` on the object returned by the `open` function